# What equipment is required to install a generator?

Tags: electrical

I am installing a generator to operate only my heating unit and a few circuits in my house. Do I need a transfer switch along with a sub-panel?

Comment: Yes.  You need a minimal transfer switch -- something to keep both the genset and the power line from being connected simultaneously.  There is a large variety of such switches of various capacities, many incorporating the "sub-panel", so it's not a burdensome task to do it "right".

Answer (score 5):

You need, at minimum, an interlock. That is a device which physically prevents the generator input and the main supply breaker from being on at the same time. Both can be off, but only one can be on. This is important for electrical line-worker safety.

If you buy or feel the need of an autostart generator, you will need to move loads to a sub-panel and have a transfer switch, so that the loads cannot overwhelm the generator when it auto-starts, and the transfer switch will automatically switch over (and serve the interlock function of keeping the generator off the main power lines.)

With a manual start generator and an interlock, you switch off most loads, start the generator, switch off the main, switch on the generator input, and can power anything on the main panel, but unless you have an absurdly large generator, not all at once.

Which suits you better depends on both your mindset and cost-sensitivity. Even without the cost differential I prefer the flexibility of having any circuit available. Other people may prefer a fully-automatic switchover more.

Comment: Most transfer switches don't require an additional panel, they tie directly into the main panel. Transfer switches are also useful for manual start generators, as they allow you to pre-select the loads you want to supply. Interlocks can be dangerous, because you have to either use a generator that can supply your total load, or select the loads on the fly. The latter can lead to overloading your generator if you don't know what you're doing, or you make a mistake.

Comment: What you describe is a "transfer switch and sub-panel" not just a transfer switch. As for overloading your generator, not even remotely true or dangerous. The generator has an output breaker and the generator input on the panel has an input breaker, either of which will protect the generator from overload. More hands on, yes. Dangerous, not remotely. If you overload it, the breaker trips, you turn a few things off, you reset the breaker. Dangerous is when the user decides to power something not on the transfer panel and gets creative with extension cords.

Comment: What I'm describing is a multi circuit transfer switch. And while it's true that generators do have safety mechanisms, it may not be wise to rely on them.

Comment: You are welcome to your paranoia, but in that case how do you manage to trust your main panel breakers, the transfer switch, the breakers in the transfer switch, the wires in your wall, and the asteroid not hitting your house before Godzilla eats it? I have two circuit breakers looking out for my generator, I'd be surprised as <bleep> if they both managed to fail on at the same time...UL thinks it's just peachy.

Comment: I guess what I'm trying to say is that with a transfer switch, you can figure out what you want to power ahead of time. Then when it comes time to use the generator, it's just a matter of flipping a few switches.  There's no thought required, and anybody in the household can do it without much instruction. I know if I'm not around, I want my family to be able to have heating/cooling ASAP. It has nothing to do with paranoia, it has to do with ease of use.